# a web editor to highlight json, just like postman's result area

Tags: javascript, editor

A web editor to highlight `json`, open source, just like postman's  result area.

It should be small, just for show content, show line numbers, highlight the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick https://ace.c9.io/. We're using it to display log files in an Admin UI. You can use regex to create custom syntax highlighting but JSON is available out of the box.